# Table Column of Scientific Notation does not line up

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c|c|c|c|c}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Verbal} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Math} \\
  \hline
  L & $\kappa\left(A^TA\right)$ & $2010$ & $\kappa\left(A^TA\right)$ & $2010$ \\
  \hline
 1 & $\num{1.000e+00}$ & $\num{1.000e+00}$ & $\num{5.466e+02}$  & $\num{5.498e+02}$\\
 2 & $\num{9.797e+11}$ & $\num{9.797e+11}$ & $\num{-1.874e+03}$ & $\num{-3.596e+02}$\\
 3 & $\num{4.728e+22}$ & $\num{4.728e+22}$ & $\num{7.069e+04}$  & $\num{4.039e+05}$\\
 4 & $\num{1.460e+27}$ & $\num{1.460e+27}$ & $\num{-2.279e+07}$ & $\num{-2.732e+08}$\\
 5 & $\num{4.128e+32}$ & $\num{4.128e+32}$ & $\num{5.379e+10}$  & $\num{1.473e+10}$\\
 6 & $\num{3.250e+40}$ & $\num{3.250e+40}$ & $\num{-1.329e+13}$ & $\num{2.339e+13}$\\
 7 & $\num{7.321e+46}$ & $\num{7.321e+46}$ & $\num{-1.230e+15}$ & $\num{-2.850e+15}$\\
 8 & $\num{9.649e+49}$ & $\num{9.649e+49}$ & $\num{-2.733e+15}$ & $\num{-3.771e+15}$\\
 9 & $\num{9.794e+56}$ & $\num{9.794e+56}$ & $\num{3.113e+14}$  & $\num{-3.080e+15}$\\
10 & $\num{1.309e+61}$ & $\num{1.309e+61}$ & $\num{-4.653e+15}$ & $\num{-2.290e+15}$\\
11 & $\num{1.557e+64}$ & $\num{1.557e+64}$ & $\num{-3.221e+15}$ & $\num{-1.338e+15}$\\
12 & $\num{2.804e+68}$ & $\num{2.804e+68}$ & $\num{2.390e+16}$  & $\num{-4.244e+16}$\\
13 & $\num{3.928e+72}$ & $\num{3.928e+72}$ & $\num{1.223e+16}$  & $\num{-2.692e+16}$\\
14 & $\num{1.816e+78}$ & $\num{1.816e+78}$ & $\num{1.779e+16}$  & $\num{-4.409e+16}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

So that is the latex code. My issue is the 2 right-most columns do not line up on the `\times` symbol (because of the negatives). How can I force it to align along the `\times` symbol?

Comment: please see the first two rows of numbers in `column 4` -- these are now aligned by using the `siunitx` package --  `S[table-format =-1.3e+2]` --which helps in the alignment -- you can remove the `\num` now from the numbers in this column -- also to protect the `header` of this column from the `siunitx` code the header has been placed in `braces` ---  `{$\kappa\left(A^TA\right)$ }` -- ali you need to do is repeat the removal of `\num` from the entire column which is tedious but elementary -- repeat the code `S[table-format =-1.3e+2]` for column 5 also thereafter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c|
                 c|
                 c|
                 S[table-format =-1.3e+2]|
                 c}
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Verbal} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Math} \\
  \hline
  L & $\kappa\left(A^TA\right)$ & $2010$ & {$\kappa\left(A^TA\right)$ }& $2010$ \\
  \hline
 1 & $\num{1.000e+00}$ & $\num{1.000e+00}$ & 5.466e+02  & $\num{5.498e+02}$\\
 2 & $\num{9.797e+11}$ & $\num{9.797e+11}$ & -1.874e+03 & $\num{-3.596e+02}$\\
 3 & $\num{4.728e+22}$ & $\num{4.728e+22}$ & $\num{7.069e+04}$  & $\num{4.039e+05}$\\
 4 & $\num{1.460e+27}$ & $\num{1.460e+27}$ & $\num{-2.279e+07}$ & $\num{-2.732e+08}$\\
 5 & $\num{4.128e+32}$ & $\num{4.128e+32}$ & $\num{5.379e+10}$  & $\num{1.473e+10}$\\
 6 & $\num{3.250e+40}$ & $\num{3.250e+40}$ & $\num{-1.329e+13}$ & $\num{2.339e+13}$\\
 7 & $\num{7.321e+46}$ & $\num{7.321e+46}$ & $\num{-1.230e+15}$ & $\num{-2.850e+15}$\\
 8 & $\num{9.649e+49}$ & $\num{9.649e+49}$ & $\num{-2.733e+15}$ & $\num{-3.771e+15}$\\
 9 & $\num{9.794e+56}$ & $\num{9.794e+56}$ & $\num{3.113e+14}$  & $\num{-3.080e+15}$\\
10 & $\num{1.309e+61}$ & $\num{1.309e+61}$ & $\num{-4.653e+15}$ & $\num{-2.290e+15}$\\
11 & $\num{1.557e+64}$ & $\num{1.557e+64}$ & $\num{-3.221e+15}$ & $\num{-1.338e+15}$\\
12 & $\num{2.804e+68}$ & $\num{2.804e+68}$ & $\num{2.390e+16}$  & $\num{-4.244e+16}$\\
13 & $\num{3.928e+72}$ & $\num{3.928e+72}$ & $\num{1.223e+16}$  & $\num{-2.692e+16}$\\
14 & $\num{1.816e+78}$ & $\num{1.816e+78}$ & $\num{1.779e+16}$  & $\num{-4.409e+16}$\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice. I appreciate this!

Answer (score 2):

You may liked the following solution:

**Edit:**

- for all columns are used `S` column type, consequently all `\num{...}` in table body are removed
- removed are all vertical lines
- for horizontal lines are used rules defined in the `booktabs` package
- for better readability, a small vertical space is inserted after every second line by `\addlinespace`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \sisetup{print-zero-exponent}
\begin{tabular}{     S[table-format=2.0, print-zero-exponent=false]
                *{2}{S[table-format =1.3e+2]}
                *{2}{S[table-format =-1.3e+2]}
                }
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Verbal}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Math}      \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
  L & {$(A^TA)$}& {2010}    & {$\kappa(A^TA)$}
                                            &  {2010}       \\
    \midrule
 1  & 1.000e+00 & 1.000e+00 &  5.466e+02    &  5.498e+02    \\
 2  & 9.797e+11 & 9.797e+11 & -1.874e+03    & -3.596e+02    \\
    \addlinespace
 3  & 4.728e+22 & 4.728e+22 &  7.069e+04    &  4.039e+05    \\
 4  & 1.460e+27 & 1.460e+27 & -2.279e+07    & -2.732e+08    \\
    \addlinespace
 5  & 4.128e+32 & 4.128e+32 &  5.379e+10    &  1.473e+10    \\
 6  & 3.250e+40 & 3.250e+40 & -1.329e+13    &  2.339e+13    \\
    \addlinespace
 7  & 7.321e+46 & 7.321e+46 & -1.230e+15    & -2.850e+15    \\
 8  & 9.649e+49 & 9.649e+49 & -2.733e+15    & -3.771e+15    \\
    \addlinespace
 9  & 9.794e+56 & 9.794e+56 &  3.113e+14    & -3.080e+15    \\
10  & 1.309e+61 & 1.309e+61 & -4.653e+15    & -2.290e+15    \\
    \addlinespace
11  & 1.557e+64 & 1.557e+64 & -3.221e+15    & -1.338e+15    \\
12  & 2.804e+68 & 2.804e+68 &  2.390e+16    & -4.244e+16    \\
    \addlinespace
13  & 3.928e+72 & 3.928e+72 &  1.223e+16    & -2.692e+16    \\
14  & 1.816e+78 & 1.816e+78 &  1.779e+16    & -4.409e+16    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

As you can see, numbers are perfectly aligned ad decimal points and since all have the same number of decimal digits also at exponent markers.

**Addendum** the very similar result is possible to achieve by use of the novel table package `tabularray``. Using it insertion of a vertical spacing done automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn {2}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
      { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \sisetup{print-zero-exponent}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {    S[table-format=2.0, print-zero-exponent=false]
                       *{2}{S[table-format = 1.3e+2]}
                       *{2}{S[table-format =-1.3e+2]}
                       },
             column{1}= {rightsep+=1.5em},
             row{3-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
             row{2,3} = {abovesep+=2pt},
             row{eachtwo} = {belowsep=1ex},
            }
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Verbal}}} 
                &           & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Math}}}
                                            &               \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{2-3}\cmidrule[l=-0.4]{4-5}
  L & \SetCell[c=1]{c} {{{$(A^TA)$}}}
                & \SetCell[c=1]{c} {{{2010}}}    
                            & \SetCell[c=1]{c} {{{$\kappa(A^TA)$}}}
                                            &  \SetCell[c=1]{c} {{{2010}}}       
                                                            \\
    \midrule
 1  & 1.000e+00 & 1.000e+00 &  5.466e+02    &  5.498e+02    \\
 2  & 9.797e+11 & 9.797e+11 & -1.874e+03    & -3.596e+02    \\
 3  & 4.728e+22 & 4.728e+22 &  7.069e+04    &  4.039e+05    \\
 4  & 1.460e+27 & 1.460e+27 & -2.279e+07    & -2.732e+08    \\
 5  & 4.128e+32 & 4.128e+32 &  5.379e+10    &  1.473e+10    \\
 6  & 3.250e+40 & 3.250e+40 & -1.329e+13    &  2.339e+13    \\
 7  & 7.321e+46 & 7.321e+46 & -1.230e+15    & -2.850e+15    \\
 8  & 9.649e+49 & 9.649e+49 & -2.733e+15    & -3.771e+15    \\
 9  & 9.794e+56 & 9.794e+56 &  3.113e+14    & -3.080e+15    \\
10  & 1.309e+61 & 1.309e+61 & -4.653e+15    & -2.290e+15    \\
11  & 1.557e+64 & 1.557e+64 & -3.221e+15    & -1.338e+15    \\
12  & 2.804e+68 & 2.804e+68 &  2.390e+16    & -4.244e+16    \\
13  & 3.928e+72 & 3.928e+72 &  1.223e+16    & -2.692e+16    \\
14  & 1.816e+78 & 1.816e+78 &  1.779e+16    & -4.409e+16    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]